# Stolen Google OAuth refresh token

Tags: oauth, macos, keychain, google-apps

I had authorized Google account on my Mac computer. I think my keychain is stolen and google oauth refresh token was stored in it. I removed the OS X app from my Google account.

1. Is the old OAuth refresh token still valid and can the thief access my google data?
2. If I reauthorize the OS X app, new oauth refresh token will be generated, will the old oauth be valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is the old OAuth refresh token still valid and can the thief access my google data?

Once app is removed the token is invalidated.

> - The user has revoked access.
> - The token has not been used for six    months.
> - The user changed passwords and the token contains Gmail    scopes.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.

See the factors which include a token expiration. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration)

> 2. If I reauthorize the OS X app, new oauth refresh token will be
>      generated, will the old oauth be valid ?

Old oauth token would be invalid.